# How to remove the action bar elevation from the material design theme?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm using the default action bar from material design and i want to remove the elevation.

I know i can remove it with `supportActionBar?.elevation  = 0F`, but is there a way to do it in the themes resources?

I tried elevation and android:elevation in this style but it does not work.

```
 <style name="Theme.Posture" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/purple_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

**try in `xml`**

```
 app:elevation="0dp"
```

**or code `Kotlin`**

```
appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener { appBarLayout, _ ->
      ViewCompat.setElevation(appBarLayout, 0f)
 })
```